# How can I do a LINQ query joining two entities and select what a Where on one of the entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have these classes:

```
public partial class AspNetRole
{
    public AspNetRole()
    {
        AspNetUsers = new HashSet<AspNetUser>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
        AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
        AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework creates these tables to hold the data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
    [Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                     NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]               NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
    [UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

What I would like to do is to get a list of AspNetUser.Id and AspNetUser.UserName where the user is in the Role with a name of "Admin". I tried this LINQ but I am getting confused with the Syntax:

```
        var result = await db.AspNetRoles
                             .Where(r => r.Name == "Admin")
                             .Select(e => new
                             {
                                 Id = e.AspNetUsers.??
                                 Name = e.AspNetUsers.??
                             .ToListAsync();
```

It seems that with Intellisense there are no properties on AspNetUsers that I can select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
  var result = db.AspNetUsers.Where(t=>t.AspNetRoles.Any(r=>r.Name == "Admin") )
                                .Select(x=>x).ToList();
```

Comment: I think thi is almost correct however I get an error with the r in intellisense.  Is the .Any in the correct place?

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this

```
var adminUsers = from user in db.AspNetUsers
                 join userRole in db.AspNetUserRoles on user.Id equals userRole.UserId
                 join role in db.AspNetRoles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                 where role.Name == "Admin"
                 select user
```